# How do you count number of rows created per day with a Datetime column?

Tags: t-sql

There are examples for this with a Date column, but I have a Datetime column.

How do you count number of rows created per day with a datetime column?

Example Data:

```
ID   CreatedDatetime
1    2017-05-21 09:14:41.022 -05:00
2    2017-05-21 07:16:49.026 -05:00
3    2017-05-23 08:18:46.023 -05:00
```

Example Output of the needed query:

```
Date           RowsCreatedOnDate
2017-05-21     2
2017-05-23     1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT cast(CreatedDatetime as Date) as [Date], count(*) As RowsCreatedOnDate
FROM [MyTable]
GROUP BY cast(CreatedDatetime as Date)
```

See it work here:

> https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d6caf210d264cc1b47e3da0cb804589a